# Problems using random forests with foreach and doMC in Yosemite OSX

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, osx-yosemite, domc

Since updating to Yosemite OSX on my late-2012 mac mini all my scripts that use foreach and doMC for parallel computation have been throwing up the following error:

```
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
```

[image: Console output]

The computations finish, but in addition to the error output in the console I'm left with 8 open zombie nodes. When executing multiple parallel scripts this results in the system getting flooded with these zombie nodes, which burn up CPU and RAM in the background, rapidly gumming up the whole process:

[image: Residual zombie nodes left in the background after executing script twice.]

Since the problem is system-dependent I'm not sure if I can provide a minimum example that will also fail on your machine, but the following script reproduces the error on mine.

```
install.packages(c('foreach', 'doMC', 'bigrf'))
library(bigrf)
data(Cars93, package="MASS")
x <- Cars93
y <- Cars93$Type
vars <- c(4:22)
forest <- bigrfc(x, y, ntree=30L, varselect=vars, cachepath=NULL)
```

Any other Yosemite users out there experiencing this? Anyone have a clue what might be going on here? I absolutely need to fix this, and would prefer to not have to do so by wiping out my hard drive and reinstalling OSX Mavericks.

Cheers,

Aaron

Comment: It looks like you're using "R Console". Do you get the error when you execute R from the terminal?

Comment: Great question--I did come across a warning at some point about implemented forked processes from a GUI. I'll try running from terminal and report back.

Comment: that's it, thank you for the help, @SteveWeston. given your extensive experience engineering this software, do you have any thoughts about why this might be cracking up in the GUI but not in BATCH mode?

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @SteveWeston, above:

The most simple way around this is to run your script file using R CMD BATCH script.R or Rscript script.R in the terminal window. E.g., save the following example as `test_case.R`

```
library(bigrf)
library(doMC)
data(Cars93, package="MASS")
registerDoMC(detectCores())
x <- Cars93
y <- Cars93$Type
vars <- c(4:22)
forest <- bigrfc(x, y, ntree=30L, varselect=vars, cachepath=NULL)
preds <- predict(forest, x)
print(preds)
```

Run this file from wherever you've saved it on your computer by changing to that drive and running Rscript test_case.R. Flawless execution, no zombie nodes. I wonder why the problem comes up in the GUI?

Thank you, Steve!

Cheers,

Aaron

Answer (score 0):

More easily you can go to `Advanced options` and unselect `Use multithreading for calculations`. This way you can avoid to fork.

That worked for me.